# Extremely slow join with join buffer

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate

I am having a problem with a complex query with multiple joins. When running EXPLAIN:

**Query**

```
explain

select ud.id from user_detail ud
cross join ticket t
cross join guest_list gl
cross join event e
cross join venue v

where t.guest_list = gl.id and gl.event = e.id and e.venue = v.id
and (ud.account = 10 or ud.venue = 10 or ud.event = 10 or ud.guest_list = 10 or t.reference_user = 10 and (ud.guest_list=t.guest_list or ud.event = gl.event or ud.venue = e.venue or ud.account = v.account) and (t.guest_list = 10))
```

**I get this:**

```
id, select_type, table, type, rows, extra
1, SIMPLE, v, index, 2, "Using index"
1, SIMPLE, e, ref, 2, "Using where; using index"
1, SIMPLE, gl, ref, 1, "Using where; using index"
1, SIMPLE, t, ref, 418, "Using where"
1, SIMPLE, ud, ALL, 44028, "Using where; Using join buffer"
```

The data model is like this:

Account <1-*> Venue <1-*> Event <1-*> GuestList <1-*> Ticket
UserDetail has an account, venue, event or guest list as a parent.

And what I am trying to do with this query is to get all of the UserDetail that has one of the specific account/venue/event/guestlist as a parent, OR that has a guestlist as a parent that has a ticket that has the reference_user field set to a specific user.

**Hibernate criteria**

```
public List<UserDetail> listUserDetails(final Collection<UserDetailNode> anyOfNodes, final User orTicketReferenceUser, final Collection<GuestList> andAnyOfGuestlistsForTicketReferenceUser, final Collection<User> anyOfUsers, final Date fromLastModificationDate, final Date toLastModificationDate, final Boolean deletedNodes, final Boolean deletedUsers, final Boolean deletedUserDetails) {

    final CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<UserDetail> cq = cb.createQuery(UserDetail.class);
    final Root<UserDetail> userDetail = cq.from(UserDetail.class);
    Predicate criteria = cb.conjunction();

    if (anyOfNodes != null || orTicketReferenceUser != null) {

        Predicate subCriteria = cb.disjunction();

        if (anyOfNodes != null) {

            Predicate anyOfNodesCriteria = cb.disjunction();

            Collection<Account> anyOfAccounts = null;
            Collection<Venue> anyOfVenues = null;
            Collection<Event> anyOfEvents = null;
            Collection<GuestList> anyOfGuestLists = null;

            final Set<UserDetailNode> anyOfNodesWithParents = new HashSet<UserDetailNode>();
            for (UserDetailNode node : anyOfNodes) {

                while (node != null) {

                    anyOfNodesWithParents.add(node);
                    node = node.getParentNode();
                }
            }

            for (final UserDetailNode node : anyOfNodesWithParents) {

                if (node instanceof Account) {

                    if (anyOfAccounts == null) anyOfAccounts = new ArrayList<Account>();
                    anyOfAccounts.add((Account)node);
                }
                else if (node instanceof Venue) {

                    if (anyOfVenues == null) anyOfVenues = new ArrayList<Venue>();
                    anyOfVenues.add((Venue)node);
                }
                else if (node instanceof Event) {

                    if (anyOfEvents == null) anyOfEvents = new ArrayList<Event>();
                    anyOfEvents.add((Event)node);
                }
                else if (node instanceof GuestList) {

                    if (anyOfGuestLists == null) anyOfGuestLists = new ArrayList<GuestList>();
                    anyOfGuestLists.add((GuestList)node);
                }
            }

            if (anyOfAccounts != null) anyOfNodesCriteria = cb.or(anyOfNodesCriteria, cb.or(userDetail.get("account").in(anyOfAccounts)));
            if (anyOfVenues != null) anyOfNodesCriteria = cb.or(anyOfNodesCriteria, cb.or(userDetail.get("venue").in(anyOfVenues)));
            if (anyOfEvents != null) anyOfNodesCriteria = cb.or(anyOfNodesCriteria, cb.or(userDetail.get("event").in(anyOfEvents)));
            if (anyOfGuestLists != null) anyOfNodesCriteria = cb.or(anyOfNodesCriteria, cb.or(userDetail.get("guestList").in(anyOfGuestLists)));

            subCriteria = cb.or(subCriteria, anyOfNodesCriteria);
        }

        if (orTicketReferenceUser != null && (andAnyOfGuestlistsForTicketReferenceUser == null || !andAnyOfGuestlistsForTicketReferenceUser.isEmpty())) {

            final Root<Ticket> ticket = cq.from(Ticket.class);
            Predicate ticketCriteria = cb.equal(ticket.get("referenceUser"), orTicketReferenceUser);
            ticketCriteria = cb.and(ticketCriteria, cb.or(cb.equal(userDetail.get("guestList"), ticket.get("guestList")), cb.equal(userDetail.get("event"), ticket.get("guestList").get("event")), cb.equal(userDetail.get("venue"), ticket.get("guestList").get("event").get("venue")), cb.equal(userDetail.get("account"), ticket.get("guestList").get("event").get("venue").get("account"))));

            if (andAnyOfGuestlistsForTicketReferenceUser != null) ticketCriteria = cb.and(ticketCriteria, ticket.get("guestList").in(andAnyOfGuestlistsForTicketReferenceUser));

            subCriteria = cb.or(subCriteria, ticketCriteria);
        }

        criteria = cb.and(criteria, subCriteria);
    }

    if (anyOfUsers != null) {

        if (anyOfUsers.isEmpty()) return new ArrayList<UserDetail>();
        criteria = cb.and(criteria, userDetail.get("user").in(anyOfUsers));
    }

    if (fromLastModificationDate != null) criteria = cb.and(criteria, cb.greaterThanOrEqualTo(userDetail.<Date>get("lastModificationDate"), fromLastModificationDate));
    if (toLastModificationDate != null) criteria = cb.and(criteria, cb.lessThanOrEqualTo(userDetail.<Date>get("lastModificationDate"), toLastModificationDate));

    cq.select(userDetail).distinct(true).where(criteria);

    return entityManager.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
}
```

From what I can see the last row is the problem, but how can I fix this? This query is auto-generated by hibernate, so I am not sure how much I can alter it.

Comment: do you have any indexes on user_detail table?

Comment: Yes, all used columns are either indexed or foreign keys

Comment: why on earth are you using cross joins for this?

Comment: This query is a cleaned up version of the query that is auto-generated by Hibernate, so it was not a personal choice

Answer (score 1):

Your over-use of cross-join Cartesian joins doesn't make sense... What is it you are actually looking for.  Since your "OR" clauses are all based on this value of 10, but then doing an implicit join to the ticket table by the guest_list id -- and finally REQUIRING the t.guest_list = 10 ?

Since all your inner joins are ALSO looking at the original user detail table having same value as result of the join. Your kicker is that the FINAL "AND" is specifically looking for  guest_list = 10.  I would immediately start with this as the basis and OR the others...  I might consider the following:

```
select STRAIGHT_JOIN
      ud.id 
   from 
      ticket t
         JOIN user_detail ud
            ON t.guest_list = ud.guest_list
   where 
          t.guest_list = 10
      AND (   ud.account = 10 
           or ud.venue = 10 
           or ud.event = 10 )
```

You make a reference to a "Reference_User = 10", but what is that context... is that like one user detail has a guest? and that guest can be associated with the same user detail event/venue/account?

By providing some sample of the details, and clarification of what you are hoping to get will get you much further ahead...

Comment: DRapp, please check my question again - I have added more information. The query itself is generated by Hibernate so it was not a personal choice. Is the ordering of the criteria important?

Comment: @PiotrBlasiak, sorry delay...  Without seeing actual data, and better context to the relationships, I don't think I can offer you much more.